# Generating a worldmap in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, 2d

I'm trying to program a little game in Java.

The world map has 100 locations (each location is either a country or either sea). 
There are 6 continents which have 4 to 15 countries. The map has 76 countries and 24 seas.
Each continent is connected to another continent with at least 1 country.

Example:

[image: Map]

As you can see the yellow continent continues at the bottom on the map.

I was thinking to store the world map in a 2D array. Bad/good idea?
To build the map, I would determine the size of the countries, pick a random spot and fill the array in a random direction to build the country.

Is this the good approach?

Comment: Do you have the map and you want to calculate the size of countries?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Is this the good approach?"
```

This question is a bit hard to answer, as it is *very* subjective.  A 2D array would work, but can be restrictive if you want to add other data/functionality later.  If you started out with an array of Colors, for example, but then wanted to add armies/whatnot, you'd have to change the array *type*, maybe to a custom `Tile` object...

If it were my game, I'd build an Interface (and then a custom Class) to represent the WorldMap.  I'd define methods, like `setCountry()`, that make sense for my game.  Now in the end I probably would back it with a 2D array (at least to start), but by creating an interface upfront, you make it a lot easier to add functionality later.  Maybe one day you want a dynamically-sized world, and now you can just swap out the 2D array with some other Collection without changing all of your game logic.

Your "filling the map" question is another wide-open question, as I can see issues with possibly enforcing your connection rules if you just go with a random fill.